# How to mock (with Moq) an interface that is serialized by Newtonsoft.json?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, json.net, moq

I mock an interface from which the object is serialized by the tested code by the Newtonsoft JsonConvert.SerializeObject.

The serializer throws an exception with the following error:

**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Self referencing loop detected for property 'Object' with type 'Castle.Proxies.IActionProxy'. Path 'Mock**'.

Newtonsoft tries to serialized the proxy object IActionProxy, that has a property Mock that loops on that serialized object.

Curiously changing serializer options

```
ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize ( ot Ignore)
PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All
```

..does not solve the problem, serialization become infinite

Thank you for help about this issue, I would be happy to have a way of using Moq in that case

**UPDATE**: here is a sample code to produce the exception:

```
Mock<IAction> _actionMock = new Mock<IAction>().SetupAllProperties();
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject( _actionMock.Object );  // JsonSerializationException (this line is in a method which i'm not responsible of )
// IAction is any interface with some properties
```

We have to consider the serialization (SerializeObject) is called by the tested code in a library I don't have access to.

Comment: have you considered mocking the call to the serializer?

Comment: More code to demonstrate what you're doing exactly, and why, would be nice. There may be no need for this at all, or else there's a need to override serialization for the interface, or else possibly for a concrete type, all of which require different approaches. In general, you don't want to be serializing mocks at all (and deserializing them is even less practical).

Comment: Yes a concrete type would prevent the crash, but my question is about finding a way of using Mocks, a concrete type requires the cumbersome task of writing callbacks to check if methods are called.

Comment: In theory, you can do this by overriding JSON.NET's default serialization policies; in practice, this is quite difficult because there is no simple way to detect at runtime if you're dealing with a mock, and even if you do there's no way to detect what type(s) it's mocking, and even if you do you don't know what type to use for serialization in any given case! You can make some ugly assumptions based on how Moq works internally, but these require reflection, and can easily break on a new release.

Comment: Consider using a concrete type that you override serialization for in the usual way (with attributes, or a custom converter, or whatever) which then internally delegates to a mock for the cumbersome stuff (or copies properties from the mock; this is easily automated over the `IAction` interface with reflection). Either that, or consider some code generation instead of a mock if the problem is the abundance of methods. The basic idea is to avoid getting a mock at the place where the serialization is supposed to happen; that's a really bad match.

Comment: @Jeroen: thank you using a concrete object instead of a Mock is the solution I adopted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a little rough around the edges, but it does the job:

```
public class JsonMockConverter : JsonConverter {
    static readonly Dictionary<object, Func<object>> mockSerializers = new Dictionary<object, Func<object>>();
    static readonly HashSet<Type> mockTypes = new HashSet<Type>();

    public static void RegisterMock<T>(Mock<T> mock, Func<object> serializer) where T : class {
        mockSerializers[mock.Object] = serializer;
        mockTypes.Add(mock.Object.GetType());
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => mockTypes.Contains(objectType);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => 
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        if (!mockSerializers.TryGetValue(value, out var mockSerializer)) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Attempt to serialize unregistered mock.");
        }
        serializer.Serialize(writer, mockSerializer());
    }
}
```

A little extension method for ease of use:

```
internal static class MockExtensions {
    public static Mock<T> RegisterForJsonSerialization<T>(this Mock<T> mock) where T : class {
        JsonMockConverter.RegisterMock(
            mock, 
            () => typeof(T).GetProperties().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.GetValue(mock.Object))
        );
        return mock;
    }
}
```

Set up as follows:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings {
    Converters = new[] { new JsonMockConverter() }
};
```

And now the following code works:

```
public interface IAction {
    int IntProperty { get; set; }
}

var actionMock = new Mock<IAction>()
    .SetupAllProperties()
    .RegisterForJsonSerialization();

var action = actionMock.Object;
action.IntProperty = 42;

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(action));
```

Making it so that you don't have to register your mocks for serialization is much harder -- there is no robust way of figuring out that an object *is* a mock, and if it is, what type it's supposed to be mocking, and if it *is*, how we're supposed to serialize that using the mock's data. This could only be done with some really nasty and brittle reflection over Moq's internals, but let's not go there. It could possibly be added to Moq itself as a feature, though.

This can be further extended with custom ways of serializing -- here I've assumed we're OK with just serializing the public properties of the mocked type. This is a little naive -- it will not work correctly if you are inheriting interfaces, for example, because `Type.GetProperties` only gets the properties declared on the interface itself. Fixing that, if desired, is left as an exercise to the reader.

Extending this for deserialization is possible in principle, but a bit trickier. It would be very unusual to need that for mocking purposes, as opposed to a concrete instance.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to debug or extend this.  I'm getting the exception when mocking an Azure.Response<SendRecipt> for a storage queue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not worrying about JsonConvert.SerializeObject() result, you can just simple add the following line into your code:

```
_actionMock.As<ISerializable>();
```

Comment: This did not work for me, still have JsonSerializationException.